# Why is ping failing in ubuntu 19.10? (seems related to IPv6)

Tags: networking, ipv6, ping

Trying ping dynazu.com gives:
joel@laptop:~$ sudo ping dynazu.com
PING dynazu.com(2600:3c01::f03c:92ff:fe3b:2efa) 56 data bytes
and never completes...

Ifconfig gives:

```
joel@laptop:~$ ifconfig -a
enp59s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 80:fa:5b:4d:02:1c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 75393  bytes 6750015 (6.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 75393  bytes 6750015 (6.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp61s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.120  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::8c22:f09:2f43:7d37  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2601:283:8100:e47:786d:47ae:6c34:cfd7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2601:283:8100:e47:18e4:8d44:9b2a:9a3f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2601:283:8100:e47:9535:577e:659b:1303  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 44:03:2c:64:ee:0c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1933500  bytes 1593080389 (1.5 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 2  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1176044  bytes 267935104 (267.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

as expected.
traceroot gives:

```
traceroute -n www.google.com
traceroute to www.google.com (172.217.12.4), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1  1.495 ms  1.529 ms  1.483 ms
 2  96.120.13.9  16.368 ms  16.282 ms  16.257 ms
 3  96.110.194.213  18.913 ms  18.979 ms  21.256 ms
 4  68.85.89.189  14.760 ms  16.986 ms  14.663 ms
 5  68.86.92.121  19.538 ms  19.506 ms  19.489 ms
 6  68.86.83.94  19.379 ms  18.511 ms  18.397 ms
 7  23.30.207.162  15.685 ms 23.30.206.218  13.349 ms 50.248.118.30  13.242 ms
 8  * * 108.170.252.193  11.894 ms
 9  216.239.49.41  18.998 ms  18.967 ms 216.239.49.43  17.238 ms
10  172.217.12.4  17.138 ms 216.239.49.43  17.598 ms 172.217.12.4  16.329 ms
```

as expected.

The website: Dynazu.com is at ip4:45.33.111.61 and pi6: 2600:3c01::f03c:92ff:fe3b:2efa

ping 45.33.111.61 gives:

```
joel@laptop:~$ ping 45.33.111.61
ping: socket: Operation not permitted
```

joel@laptop:~$ sudo ping 45.33.111.61 gives:

```
PING 45.33.111.61 (45.33.111.61) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 45.33.111.61: icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=40.1 ms
64 bytes from 45.33.111.61: icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=40.3 ms
64 bytes from 45.33.111.61: icmp_seq=3 ttl=51 time=39.8 ms
64 bytes from 45.33.111.61: icmp_seq=4 ttl=51 time=40.3 ms
```

So why does ping fail with authentication?

ping 2600:3c01::f03c:92ff:fe3b:2efa gives:

```
ping: socket: Operation not permitted
```

sudo ping 2600:3c01::f03c:92ff:fe3b:2efa gives:

```
joel@laptop:~$ sudo ping 2600:3c01::f03c:92ff:fe3b:2efa
PING 2600:3c01::f03c:92ff:fe3b:2efa(2600:3c01::f03c:92ff:fe3b:2efa) 56 data bytes
```

and no more.

Any ideas?

Comment: To ping an IPv6 address, using `ping6`, not `ping`. sudo is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Find out where the ping package is.It might have a different location. On my Ubuntu 18.04 machine, it is in `/bin`.
Use `type -a ping` to locate it. Next, verify that it is there and is owned by `root` and is permed 755 (or similar)

```
ls -lsa /bin/ping
sudo chmod 4711 /bin/ping
```

Verify that the fix worked `ls -lsa /bin/ping`

```
ping 2600:3c01::f03c:92ff:fe3b:2efa
```